# Replacing h1 tag conditional statement

Tags: javascript, css, syntax

I am working on the page with a pretty simple layout: H1 followed by an image then by H2. The content is dynamically generated so if there is no image the layout changes from H1 followed by H2. When this happens the text in H2 has to be centered on the screen in place of the image. I created another style called H3 so that when there is no image, and H1 is followed immediately by H2 that H2 then becomes H3.

```
$('h2').replaceWith(function() {
   if ('h2' after 'h1') {
      return $("<h3 />", { html: $(this).html() });
   } )
```

I cannot seem to get the syntax correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS's adjacent sibling selector (+):

```
h1 + h2 { text-align:center; }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

```css
h1 { text-align:center; }
h1 + img + h2 { background-color:red; }
h1 + h2 { text-align:center; }
```

```html
<h1>H1</h1>
  <img src="#"/>
  <h2>H2</h2>
<hr>
<h1>H1</h1>
  <h2>H2</h2>
```

Comment: Can it really be that simple? I was thinking about this all wrong. Thank you!